# Flutter delete an item in ListView.builder onTap of a button

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, listviewitem

I've create a ListView.builder to allow the user to add multiple credit cards.
To delete of them he would just check the card, and press the button 'Delete a card'.
Inside the class `InputAddCarte` I've created a widget called `_getItemChecked` where I select the checked card and once my button is pressed I use removeAt to delete it.
My problem is that it doesn't work, it keeps telling me:

```
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
```

While if you check in the consolde of my dartPad, when I print the index it's either 0 or 1 (hence why I put index-1 in the code). If someone could help me find what I am doing wrong would be super nice!
Here is the code: https://dartpad.dev/b0aaaa2901aa3ac67426d9bdd885abb1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to decrease your variable 'value' by one when removing an item from the list!

Comment: where should I do that?

Comment: Because I tried to add this in the setState of my delete's button but it tells me it's an unnecessary statement. If you could provide more informations that would be awesome

Comment: setState(() { count -= 1; ...});

Comment: indeed, adding `onPressed: () { setState(() {value -= 1; _selectedList.removeAt(index - 1);  }); },` did the trick! thanks :)